# how can i add a separator gif between two content areas something like this?

Tags: html, css

I mean that there are two contents on the body, content left and content right, i would like to do content right as a menu panel and put a separator gif (feathered vertical line) between of them. Please tell me how can i do it ? What is the css code? Thanks.

Comment: http://i50.tinypic.com/a40ub9.png i just want to do this, with two columns, possible?

Comment: can you post your code gulada........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see you can get your desired result through easy code :-

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">left-panel</div>     
<div class="right">right-panel</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
border:1px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
width:220px
}

.left {
float:left;
width:100px;
height:280px;  
background:grey; 
position:relative;
}

.left:after {
position:absolute;
content:" ";
width:1px; 
height:280px;
background-color: #FAFAFA;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000000), to(#FAFAFA));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #FAFAFA 100%);  
right:-10px;
top:0;  
}
.right {
float:right;
width:100px;
height:280px;  
background:lightgrey;  
}
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/cjA4Jg5d)**

Answer (score 0):

```
#vertical {
    border-left:thick solid #ffff00;
}
```

This should work